# Changing variable value on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<label>
    <select id="length" size="1" name="example_length" class="form-control" aria-controls="example">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>

    records per page</label>  

$('#tableAll').each(function () {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 10;
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function (event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
    }
    $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

I have selection in HTML and I have javascript function that is paginating data inside of a table. How to change var numPerPage based on selection in HTML? Thanks.

Comment: you have two basic options, you can bind a listener to the select element, or (my preferred), put an `onChange="doFunction(this)"`  on the select element.  You prefer one over the other?

Comment: is it posibble to do it with change function? but what goes inside {} in if statement

Comment: $( "#length" ).change(function () {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("value") === "25"){

  }
    });
  }).change();

Comment: that looks good, (no regard to formatting), does it work as intended?

Comment: no beacause there is nothing inside {} in if statement...I need to  set value of var numPerPage to 25. I've tried some options but I don't know how to do it because var numPerPage is local variable and I want to stay that way :)

Comment: I see...  this is a bit hackey, sorry in a hurry... but you could potentially define `numPerPage` as 
`var numPerPage = $("#length").val();`
that will set it based on the current selection...

Comment: thanks but It's not working, table is always displaying only 10 results, it's not reacting on selection

Comment: yes you need to call (or recall) the anonymous function after you change the selection...

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the numPerPage variable like this

```
$( "#length" ).change(function() {
      var numPerPage = $("#length").val());
});
```

Then you can call it where you will run your function

Comment: you defined a local variable which it's scope ends just within the change callback

Answer (score 0):

You can do pagination on `change()` event of the select.

```
$( "#length" ).change(function() {
    var numPerPage = $(this).val();
          $('#tableAll').each(function () {
        var currentPage = 0;
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
            $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        });
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
        var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
            $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                newPage: page
            }, function (event) {
                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
        }
        $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
    });
    });
```